# Compiling Qt 5.3 from sources fails

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, qml, qt5

I am compiling Qt 5.3 from sources and I am getting errors, in particular this one:

```
error: ‘QV4::Property::Property(const QV4::Property&)’ is private
```

My configure options are:

```
./configure -no-compile-examples -no-opengl -no-openssl -no-fontconfig
```

This is the result of gmake:

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/niko/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.1/qtdeclarative/src/qml'
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-exceptions -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_MTDEV -DQT_NO_LIBUDEV -DQT_NO_URL_CAST_FROM_STRING -DQT_NO_INTEGER_EVENT_COORDINATES -DQT_BUILD_QML_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x050000 -DWTF_EXPORT_PRIVATE= -DJS_EXPORT_PRIVATE= -DWTFReportAssertionFailure=qmlWTFReportAssertionFailure -DWTFReportBacktrace=qmlWTFReportBacktrace -DWTFInvokeCrashHook=qmlWTFInvokeCrashHook -DENABLE_LLINT=0 -DENABLE_DFG_JIT=0 -DENABLE_DFG_JIT_UTILITY_METHODS=1 -DENABLE_JIT_CONSTANT_BLINDING=0 -DBUILDING_QT__ -DWTF_USE_UDIS86=0 -DNDEBUG -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/home/niko/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.1/qtbase/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I../../include -I../../include/QtQml -I../../include/QtQml/5.3.1 -I../../include/QtQml/5.3.1/QtQml -Icompiler -I. -I../3rdparty/masm/jit -I../3rdparty/masm/assembler -I../3rdparty/masm/runtime -I../3rdparty/masm/wtf -I../3rdparty/masm/stubs -I../3rdparty/masm/stubs/wtf -I../3rdparty/masm -I../3rdparty/masm/disassembler -I../3rdparty/masm/disassembler/udis86 -Ijit -I. -Ijsruntime -I. -I../3rdparty/double-conversion -Idebugger -Ianimations -I/home/niko/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.1/qtbase/include -I/home/niko/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.1/qtbase/include/QtNetwork -I/home/niko/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.1/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.3.1 -I/home/niko/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.1/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.3.1/QtCore -I/home/niko/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.1/qtbase/include/QtCore -I.moc -o .obj/qqmllistaccessor.o util/qqmllistaccessor.cpp
../../include/QtQml/5.3.1/QtQml/private/../../../../../src/qml/jsruntime/qv4managed_p.h: In constructor ‘QV4::ManagedRef::ManagedRef(const QV4::Scoped<QV4::Managed>&)’:
../../include/QtQml/5.3.1/QtQml/private/../../../../../src/qml/jsruntime/qv4managed_p.h:364: warning: lowering visibility of ‘QV4::Value* QV4::extractValuePointer(const QV4::Scoped<T>&) [with T = QV4::Managed]’ to match its type
../../include/QtQml/5.3.1/QtQml/private/../../../../../src/qml/jsruntime/qv4string_p.h: In function ‘QV4::ReturnedValue QV4::value_convert(QV4::ExecutionEngine*, const QV4::Value&) [with T = QV4::String]’:
../../include/QtQml/5.3.1/QtQml/private/../../../../../src/qml/jsruntime/qv4string_p.h:189: warning: lowering visibility of ‘QV4::ReturnedValue QV4::value_convert(QV4::ExecutionEngine*, const QV4::Value&) [with T = QV4::String]’ to match its type
../../include/QtQml/5.3.1/QtQml/private/../../../../../src/qml/jsruntime/qv4managed_p.h: In constructor ‘QV4::StringRef::StringRef(const QV4::Scoped<QV4::String>&)’:../../include/QtQml/5.3.1/QtQml/private/../../../../../src/qml/jsruntime/qv4managed_p.h:364: warning: lowering visibility of ‘QV4::Value* QV4::extractValuePointer(const QV4::Scoped<T>&) [with T = QV4::String]’ to match its type
../../include/QtQml/5.3.1/QtQml/private/../../../../../src/qml/jsruntime/qv4property_p.h: In member function ‘void QV4::Object::insertMember(QV4::StringRef, QV4::ValueRef, QV4::PropertyAttributes)’:
../../include/QtQml/5.3.1/QtQml/private/../../../../../src/qml/jsruntime/qv4property_p.h:101: error: ‘QV4::Property::Property(const QV4::Property&)’ is private
../../include/QtQml/5.3.1/QtQml/private/../../../../../src/qml/jsruntime/qv4object_p.h:171: error: within this context
make[3]: *** [.obj/qqmllistaccessor.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/niko/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.1/qtdeclarative/src/qml'
make[2]: *** [sub-qml-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/niko/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.1/qtdeclarative/src'
make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/niko/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.1/qtdeclarative'
make: *** [module-qtdeclarative-make_first] Error 2
-bash-3.2$
```

How do i fix it ? My system info is:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --disable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
$ rpm -qa|grep relea
redhat-release-5Server-5.9.0.2
redhat-release-notes-5Server-46
$ uname -a
Linux mapserver03 2.6.18-348.el5 #1 SMP Wed Nov 28 21:22:00 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$
$ pwd
/home/niko/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.1
$
```

Comment: Use *at least* GCC 4.6, not less.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your gcc is too old. You can fix it by installing a newer gcc (say from sources, in your $HOME prefix).

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue and already reported on the Qt bug tracker:

[Compile error due to attempt to use private constructor](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-38568)

This may or may not be fixed upstream depending on the root cause of the issue.

That being said, building Qt 5.3 with gcc 4.1.2 (!) is a brave activity. I would suggest to update that regardless this issue.

**Edit:** It seems that this was fixed in the development version, so you can probably backport the fix to your released tarball and try again. Alternatively, you can try the latest development version.

https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/84760/